# Using int array as input for const unsigned char*

Tags: c, arrays, image, png, lodepng

So I had my code working all fine when having this function, creating a greyscale PNG from a `short` array containing all pixel values. The function worked perfectly fine...

I'm not the best in C so be warned for perhaps some weird code:

```
void exportPNG(const char* filename, short image[], int npixels, int w, int h){
    int i = 0;
    char file_out[npixels];

    while (i < npixels){
        file_out[i] = (char)image[i];
        i++;
    }

    lodepng_encode_file(filename, file_out, w, h, LCT_GREY, 8); // function from lodepng for encoding/decoding of PNGs
}
```

As you can see, I use [lodepng](https://lodev.org/lodepng/) to eventually create a PNG from pixel grey values contained in `image[]`. This all went fine until I realised I had to change my image array to an `int` array instead of `short` array for some new functionality added to my complete code.

To make sure I could still export to PNG, I also changed this function by changing the `short image[]` to `int image[]`:

```
void exportPNG(const char* filename, int image[], int npixels, int w, int h{}
```

After this change, I suddenly got images containing only the upper-left quadrant of the actual image with extra noise (probably the corrupted/missing pixel values, the noise is not present as fixed black or white columns/rows but appears random to the eye).

I also tried being more explicit like using `unsigned char file_out[npixels]` and also adding a `'\0'` in the `file_out[npixels+1]` but nothing works nor changes. I also tried using a `unsigned char* file_out[npixels]` in combination with a `unsigned char c[sizeof(int)]` to copy the integers to a character pointer array with `strcpy()`, but I get weird black and white patterns instead of an image. My best guess here is probably because I had to use `*file_out` in the lodepng function??

Just in case it's good to know: lodepng_encode_file requires a `const unsigned char* image` variable as pixel data, this is why I really need to get a char array instead of that int array.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

UPDATE:
After the comments, I also decided to give more info on how the image was acquired and made me realise that I never had any problems when using `short` arrays. First off, the images are available to me as binary files, this is because I will eventually have to use sensor data and wanted to get some sort of feel for a binary stream. They are read in using `fread()`.

Today I also tested it with my previous code using a `short` array and that works perfectly again. Sooo I guess the best way to do this is just to use `short` arrays. I'm gonna try and refurbish my other functions to work with `short` arrays and then hopefully everything is fine again.

Comment: `char` is usually 8 bits, and may be unsigned. `int` is usually 32 bits, and is always `signed`. How do you fit a 32-bit signed value into an 8-bit (possibly unsigned) value? There's probably no need for your temporary `char` array even, why don't you just pass `image` itself to the `lodepng_encode_file` function?

Comment: If the function requires `const unsigned char* image` you should use `unsigned char file_out[npixels];`. How do you write the image data into your `short image[]` or `int image[]`? Maybe you should also show the calling function. Can your `image` array contain data that cannot be represented in an `unsigned char`?

Comment: Thanks for both comments! Sadly, passing down the `image` array didn't work.. I did look at how I previously did it and how the data was read in and it appears it simply only works with `short` arrays. I updated my question just in case anyone else has the same problem.